# "Navigate Backwards" functionality in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

In Visual Studio there's a function called "Navigate Backwards" that works as an undo/redo buffer for mouse click carat placement.  In other words, it remembers the places you've clicked on in a document and allows you to go back to them.

Is there a similar function in Microsoft Word 2010?  There's a "back" command, but it only works for hyperlinks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try CTRL-ALT-Z

I think that should be what you are after?

Comment: That's pretty close, and as close as I think I'll get.  Thank you!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff967491.aspx  "Cycle through the locations of your last four edits "

Comment: FYI: The button for this is called "Previous Edit"

Comment: No it isn't previous edit @greg it will go back even if you haven't edited anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Back button that you can add to the Ribbon Toolbar (in all commands).
Hotkey is Alt+Left